# Determinant calculation - Bareiss vs. Gauss Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I've been working on a matrix-library in C++ for a while and amongst other functions, I've implemented two functions for calculating the determinant of a matrix:

## Gauss-Algorithm:

This algorithm is based on the fact that the determinant of a triangular matrix equals the product of it's diagonal entries. Therefore it is pretty intuitive to convert the matrix into a triangular matrix by using elementary row operations.

My implementation:

```
double getDeterminantGauss(std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix) {
    int n = matrix.size();
    int sign = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        //Pivot - row swap needed
        if(matrix[i][i] == 0) {
            int m = 0;
            for(m = i + 1; m < n; m++) {
                if(matrix[m][i] != 0) {       
                    swap(matrix[m], matrix[i]);
                    sign = -sign;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //No entries != 0 found in column k -> det = 0
            if(m == n) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            double ratio = matrix[j][i] / matrix[i][i];
            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                matrix[j][k] -= ratio * matrix[i][k];
            }
        }
    }

    double solution = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        solution *= matrix[i][i];
    }

    return sign * solution;
}
```

## Bareiss-Algorithm:

The Bareiss-Algorithm was introduced by Erwin Bareiss in his paper "Sylvester's Identity and multistep integer-preserving Gaussian elimination" (1968) and is mathematically quite complex (the interested can read the paper [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-103/S0025-5718-1968-0226829-0/S0025-5718-1968-0226829-0.pdf)). One advantage of this algorithm over Gauss is the following: To calculate the determinant of a integer determinant, only integer arithmetic is needed: Any division performed will have no remainder.

My implementation:

```
double getDeterminantBareiss(std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect) {
    int dim = vect.size();

    if(dim <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    double sign = 1;

    for(int k = 0; k < dim - 1; k++) {

        //Pivot - row swap needed
        if(vect[k][k] == 0) {
            int m = 0;
            for(m = k + 1; m < dim; m++) {
                if(vect[m][k] != 0) {       
                    swap(vect[m], vect[k]);
                    sign = -sign;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //No entries != 0 found in column k -> det = 0
            if(m == dim) {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        //Apply formula
        for (int i = k + 1; i < dim; i++) {
            for (int j = k + 1; j < dim; j++) {
                vect[i][j] = vect[k][k] * vect[i][j] - vect[i][k] * vect[k][j];
                if(k != 0) {
                    vect[i][j] /= vect[k-1][k-1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sign * vect[dim-1][dim-1];
}
```

## Complexity:

Obviously both these algorithnms have a time-complexity of $\mathcal{O}{(n^3)}$. The Laplace-expansion here is not really an alternative with $\mathcal{O}{(n!)}$.

## Question:

Why is the Gauss-Algorithm much more often used than the Bareiss-Algorithm? Is the Gauss-Algorithm just better? If yes, why?

Comment: Thank you for posting such a clear impl of Bareiss. I adapted this for my own (toy) matrix class, in place of the naive Laplace, & found it passed all existing tests, FAR faster. In contrast, Gauss elimination failed via losing fractional parts. But I saw another interesting point: when using Laplace with a matrix containing `int`s, it seems it can overflow or otherwise be undefined: my tests found a 10x10 matrix of `int`s between `0` and `100`, whose det should be 0 - & which Bareiss rightly concludes but Laplace gets wrong. So the Bareiss algo might be more stable here too. Btw, nice avatar!

Comment: @underscore_d Thank you! If you are interested in the background of the algorithm, I suggest reading https://www.math.usm.edu/perry/Research/Thesis_DRL.pdf (pages 25 and following)

Comment: Yup, that's a fun read! :-D I first found a link to another implementation, [on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/700259/350541), but as a comment noted, it can't handle division by 0. They linked that thesis, which solves it as you do, by swapping rows.